# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class Button in API 18

Tags: android, android-layout, button

My app runs in API 23, but it is not working in API 18 and throws an exception.
Any idea why it throws an exception in API 18?

Here is code of my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment_when_read_more_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_next_arrow"
    android:drawableTint="#666666"
    android:text="더 보기"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Comment: `android:drawableTint` was added in api 23. So it will not work with api 18.

Comment: That shouldn't cause a crash, though. It'll just be ignored on versions that don't have it. Look further on in the stack trace for the root Exception. An `InflateException` does not tell you much itself.

Comment: You mention below that it runs on 5.0. What type of drawable is `ic_next_arrow`? If it's a vector drawable, that's your problem.

Comment: ic_next_arrow is vector image?

Comment: yes. ic_next_arrow is vector image.

Answer (score 0):

remove android:drawableTint="#666666" it will not work on API 18..it was added for api level 23 and above.

if you still wish to use it use below code to do it programmatically.

```
private void setTintedCompoundDrawable(Button button , int drawableRes, int tintRes) {
button .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        null,  // Left
        Utils.tintDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableRes),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), tintRes)), // Top
        null, // Right
        null); //Bottom
// if you need any space between the icon and text.
button.setCompoundDrawablePadding(12);
```

}

Comment: I deleted android: drawableTint = "# 666666". But I got the same error. It also runs in API 5.0, where the tint attribute does not apply. thank you for answer